# Writing to memory mapped GPIO-registers does not write anything

Tags: arm, stm32, gpio

On my NUCLEO-H7A3ZI-Q, I am trying to make the LED at port PB7 turn on using assembly. According to the STM32H7A3 reference manual, port B is mapped at address `0x50820400` (page 129):

[image: Reference manual on Register boundary addresses]

The following code should write the value `0xc0` to the address `0x50820400`, pointing into the first byte of `GPIOB_MODER`, which is `rw`:

```
.section .text

reset_handler:
    nop

    ldr r0, GPIO_ADDR
    mov r1, #0xc0
    strb r1, [r0]

done:
    b done

.align 2
GPIO_ADDR:  .word 0x58020400

.section .vectors
.word 0x20001ffe    @ Initial SP
.word reset_handler @ Entrypoint
```

However, this does not work. Looking at the memory using STM32CubeProgrammer before and after the `strb` instruction gives the same value `0xFFFFFEBF` at `0x58020400` before and after the write instruction.

The value `0xFFFFFEBF` is the reset value of `GPIOB_MODER`, which makes sense. However, all other values in the memory mapped region are also `0xFFFFFEBF`, whereas the documentation states the reset value of some other values should not be `0xFFFFFEBF`. This might suggest that I have missed some type of initialization step, but I could not find anything in the manual that states something like that should be necessary, but the manual is ~3000 pages, so I might have missed something :)

Comment: 1) enable gpiob, look in the RCC section 2) modify moder.  For reasons I suspect I know why, they allow reads of moder when the peripheral is disabled and/or the logic spits back the reset value.  But to write the peripheral you first need to enable clocks to it.

Comment: quite typical in microcontrollers that you have to enable each peripheral before you use it, knowing that the 3000 pages becomes much much smaller.  Some vendors spell it out, some dont and assume you know.

Comment: In the current doc search for GPIOBEN

Comment: this is a 32 bit register use str not strb.   be careful to have a couple of clocks/instructions between the store to the rcc register and the store to moder as there can be a race condition depending on the chip and the write wont work.  Most folks use a read-modify-write (read, zero the bits, set the bits, write) and that is more than enough clocks for the enable to pass through.

Comment: "Each I/O port bit is freely programmable, however the I/O port registers have to be
accessed as 32-bit words, half-words or bytes."  use strb if you want.  In general with control and status registers, dont assume you can break them up and access parts, assume you have to match the width perfectly unless otherwise documented.

Comment: Thank you! Writing to the RCC register "unlocked" the memory!

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable GPIO peripheral clock first. RCC register is used for that.

I would rather discourage you from learning STM32 uCs using assembler. It is the way to nowhere.

Start from the programming manual & reference manual where ARM uCs low level programming is described. Clocks, peripherals etc etc